# The following issues occur while installing mysql

Tags: linux, mysql

The following issues occur while installing `mysql`

```
update-alternatives: using /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf to provide /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my.cnf) in auto mode
dpkg: error processing package mysql-community-server (--configure):
installed mysql-community-server package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:mysql-server depends on mysql-community-server (= 8.0.30-1ubuntu18.04); however:
  Package mysql-community-server is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1.5) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-community-server
 mysql-server
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: As @roaima pointed out, what is the question? We also have to guess if you are using Ubuntu or a derivative and the version. Can you add which distribution and release you are using?